# maven project property for installation directory of generated artifact

Tags: properties, maven

I have a maven project that generates a jar file, and i want to be able to execute that jar after it has been installed in my local maven repo.  I have all the project properties I need in order to be able to construct the directory path to the jar.  But, the problem I'm having is converting ${project.groupId} to a platform independent directory path.  For example, the artifact gets installed here:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\myusername\.m2\repository\edu\ucd\chem\springbatch\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\springbatch-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

So, to construct that path using maven project properties, I have:

```
${settings.localRepository}${file.separator}${project.groupId}${file.separator}${project.name}${file.separator}${project.version}${file.separator}${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}
```

That generates:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\myusername\.m2\repository\edu.ucd.chem\springbatch\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\springbatch-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

The only problem is that the groupId (edu.ucd.chem) isn't converted to a directory path (edu/ucd/chem).  Is there a maven property already for this?  Or do I need to manually convert the periods (.) to whatever file.separator I have?  If I have to do it manually, how do I accomplish that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, maybe you can launch the generated jar in your target folder `${project.build.directory}`instead.

Comment: Yeah, I'll prob just end up doing that.  Kinda odd there's no property for this sort of thing...

Answer (score 0):

While not an answer to the question, [maven dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html) has a `useRepositoryLayout` parameter, which constructs the same directory layout as the repository.